# How can I randomly select an element in Ocaml?

Tags: random, ocaml

In my program in OCaml, I need to randomly select a string from a huge set of strings. I've tried two different ways of doing this so far, each with little success. I first stored all of the strings into a list and then would randomly select an element from the list:

```
let randomelement l =
    List.nth l (Random.int (List.length l))
```

But this takes a long time if it selects the 1000th string in the list. So I put it all into a set, thinking that `Set.choose` would return a random element from the set. But that doesn't seem to be working. I guess I have two questions...how does `Set.choose` work, and is there a better way to randomly select an element in Ocaml?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you care about selection speed you should use a different container. Why use List with access in O(n) or Set with O(log n) when you can use Array with O(1) i.e. constant time.

To adjust your example:

```
let randomelement arr =
    let n = Random.int (Array.length arr) in
    Array.get arr n;;
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know arrays were O(1) time. That's awesome and that's what I'll do. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`Set.choose` is an alias for `Set.min_elt`; although it may not be in the future.

`List.nth` would surely suck if you had to do it very often.

An array will work great, but if you have to add more elements, or delete elements, this could be a book-keeping nightmare.

Take a look at implementations of [Random Access Lists](http://www.eecs.usma.edu/webs/people/okasaki/pubs.html#fpca95), which have pretty optimal time for insertion, deletion, lookup, and cardinal without being constrained to arrays.

When I originally ran into this problem, I extended the implementation of `Set` and `Map` to include `random` and `nth`. To extend a module, you need to re-implement the structure and add identity functions to convert between the two. I wrote a new module, called `XSet`, with the following boilerplate:

```
module Make (Ord : Set.OrderedType) =
    struct
        include Set.Make(Ord)

        type impl = Empty | Node of impl * elt * impl * int

        external impl_of_t : t -> impl = "%identity"
        external t_of_impl : impl -> t = "%identity"

        ...
    end
```

You will have to use `impl_of_t` and vice versa to call normal `Set` functions, or call your personal ones from the passed arguments --what gets passed to your function should be `Set.Make`'s implementation `t` not `impl`.

Comment: Interesting technique to extend the standard library, but your implementation of `nth` for sets is O(n), right? (you might as well use `iter`)

Comment: Yeah, I think it is; I used an in-order traversal to count elements. I had similar code from the `Map` module when I needed to find the `cardinality` of the `Map` structure, so it was quite easy to get things going, and eventually changed over to the RAL data-structure.

Comment: After recalling the code a bit more, I had started writing the random function with intention to not have it O(n), but I came to the conclusion it wasn't possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Storing the size of each subtree in the node would allow to navigate the tree with probabilities of descent proportional to the number of elements. On node N with subnodes S1 and S2, pick an equiprobable random number r between 0 and size(S1)+size(S2). If r=0, return the element carried by N. If 1 <= r <= size(S1), go left, otherwise, go right.

Comment: That is true, but then I would have to re-implement the `Set` module completely. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, Set.choose is deterministic, and I think it's specified in the documentation. I think in the current implementation it returns the minimum element.

In which data structure is your set of string stored in the first place ? An easy way to get a random element is to count the number of different strings you have, pick a random number K in between, and get the "K-th string" you have. This can be done rather efficiently for some data structure (eg for arrays, it's a constant time operation), less efficiently for others.

Answer (score 3):

Your question implies that you have all the time you want to prepare the structure that contains the strings, and that then, you will pick several times at random without changing the set.

If this is correct, then I would recommend to store them in an array. This gives the fastest access to a random element (direct once you have picked a random index). Sets and list implementation are all inconvenient to access the i-th element once you have picked a random index i (although, for Sets, if you do not mind a random choice with poor randomness, you could pick a random path in the binary tree that represents the set. You can't do that from outside the implementation but you could copy-paste it and add your function inside the module).

Answer (score 2):

First off, there's a List.nth function which could replace your helper function.

```
let n = Random.int (List.length lst) in
    List.nth n lst ;;
```

(though this would not be any faster since I'm pretty sure it does just about the same thing as your helper function does)

As far as speeding this up goes: if the number of strings you have is fixed, you could use an Array which would speed things up quite a lot as the access time for an Array is constant.

Answer (score 1):

`Set.choose` guarantees that it will choose the same element every time for a given set.  Which element it chooses is not specified, but if you look at the source code for it you'll see that it returns the minimum element.

Your best bet is to use an array.  If you want an immutable data structure instead, then I would suggest a map keyed on integers.